# WordPress - display list of category from database

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to create a list where I will extract the parameters from a particular category. The parameters that should be are "Title", "Author", "Number of views".

I installed the plugin and tried to call the database parameters, but it does not work. I use the Divine Theme with the Divi Builder editor.

This is how I want to create.
[image]

Do you have an idea of how to do it?
Thanks!

Comment: _it doesn't work_, is not going to help us figure out your problem, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I found solution. Install plugin "List-Category-Post" and modify code, create new template.  [Here is GitHub link](https://github.com/picandocodigo/List-Category-Posts)